# Select tag dropdown arrow

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, select

I am having issues in aligning arrow to right in chrome as shown in images:

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

effective css acting on select tag is :

```
 select {
            padding: 2px 5px 5px 20px;
            width: 90%;
            margin: 0;
            background: #f8f8f8;
            color: #888;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            outline: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

And HTML is

```
    <select class="qt_select" name="q3">
         <option value="pa_answeroption:704">1</option>
         <option value="pa_answeroption:705">2</option>
         <option value="pa_answeroption:706">3</option>
         <option value="pa_answeroption:707">4</option>
         <option value="pa_answeroption:708">5</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: What is your selector?

Comment: applying css to select tag directly

Comment: And what's the HTML, where's the arrow coming from? Is it an image of some sort?

Comment: :) I edited question. Its nothing fancy

Comment: Generally not a good idea to try to style form controls too much. You're never going to get a consistent look cross browsers. Have you seen what the dropdowns look like in IE/iPhone/Android yet?

Anyway: there is some other CSS causing that issue. Here's a JSFiddle built using the code you provided:

http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/SRJrg/

Looks fine on Chrome.